# Flink Kafka - Custom Class Data is always null

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization, apache-flink

Custom Class

**Person**

```
class Person
{
  private Integer id;
  private String name; 
 //getters and setters
}
```

**Kafka Flink Connector**

```
TypeInformation<Person> info = TypeInformation.of(Person.class);
TypeInformationSerializationSchema schema = new TypeInformationSerializationSchema(info, new ExecutionConfig());
DataStream<Person> input = env.addSource( new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("persons", schema , getKafkaProperties()));
```

Now if I send the below json

```
{ "id" : 1, "name": Synd }
```

through Kafka Console Producer, the flink code throws **null pointer exception**
But if I use `SimpleStringSchema` instead of CustomSchema as defined before, the stream is getting printed.

What is wrong in the above setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for who have the same question

**Custom Serializer**

```
class PersonSchema implements DeserializationSchema<Person>{

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        return mapper.readValue( bytes, Person.class );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Person person) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Person> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Person>(){});
    }
}
```

**Using the schema**

```
DataStream<Person> input = env.addSource( new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("persons", new PersonSchema() , getKafkaProperties()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeInformationSerializationSchema` is a de-/serialization schema which uses Flink's serialization stack and, thus, also its serializer. Therefore, when using this `SerializationSchema` Flink expects that the data has been serialized with Flink's serializer for the `Person` type.

Given the excerpt of the `Person` class, Flink will most likely use its `PojoTypeSerializer`. Feeding JSON input data won't be understood by this serializer.

If you want to use JSON as the input format, then you have to define your own `DeserializationSchema` which can parse JSON into `Person`.

Comment: Worked!  A better documentation would have helped