# How to apply conditions on Flink events?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have implemented this

[Flink Kafka - Custom Class Data is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139625/flink-kafka-custom-class-data-is-always-null/51146847#51146847).

I gone thru the above link and implemented the same but how to apply condition on the events.

```
Pattern<Person, ?> eventspattern = Pattern.<Person> begin("first")
                    .subtype(Person.class).where(new SimpleCondition<Person>() {

                        public boolean filter(Person value) {
                            if (value.getid() == 1) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
}).within(Time.seconds(10));
```

How do i implement the alerts like "find person id" for the above condition.

I tried with above code it doesn't print anything.
can any one please help on this request

Comment: Have you checked that in the input data there is actually a `Person` with id `1`?

Comment: Yes. I checked that but its not printing the record in console. how to implement that if id is s i just make it alert

Comment: I think the above code is correct?

Comment: @TillRohrmann Do you have any idea how to create alert. can you please help on this